# Python and sqlite3 - adding thousands of rows

Tags: python, sql, django, sqlite

I have a .sql file containing thousands of individual insert statements.  It takes forever to do them all.  I am trying to figure out a way to do this more efficiently.  In python the sqlite3 library can't do things like ".read" or ".import" but executescript is too slow for that many inserts.

I installed the sqlite3.exe shell in hopes of using ".read" or ".import" but I can't quite figure out how to use it.  Running it through django in eclipse doesn't work because it expects the database to be at the root of my C drive which seems silly.  Running it through the command line doesn't work because it can't find my database file (unless I'm doing something wrong)

Any tips?

Thanks!

Comment: what are you trying to do? Execute thousands of insert statements on a sqlite3 database?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you using transactions ? SQLite will create a transaction for every [insert statement individually by default](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html), which slows things way down.

> By default, the sqlite3 module opens
>   transactions implicitly before a Data
>   Modification Language (DML) statement
>   (i.e. INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE/REPLACE)

If you manually create one single transaction at the start and commit it at the end instead,  it will speed things up a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try running the inserts inside a single transaction?
If not then each insert is treated as a transaction and .. well, you can read the SQLite FAQ for this [here](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q19)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to running the queries in bulk inside a single transaction, also try `VACUUM` and `ANALYZE`ing the database file. It helped a similar problem of mine.

Answer (score 1):

Use a parameterized query

and

Use a transaction.